# Wingpanel clock to display in 12-hour format?

Tags: settings

How can I set the clock to display 12-hour format? Example 1:45 PM instead of 13:45.

My Language & Region settings are: Language: English; Numbers and dates: Spanish (Mexico)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To select the 12-hour format:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime time-format 12-hour
```

To return to the 24-hour format:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime time-format 24-hour
```

Comment: For some reason the clock actually disappeared after trying the first line. Now I went to Dconf-editor and looked under `com.canonical.indicator.datetime` and `show-clock` is `true` so I don't know what's wrong...

Comment: @Jorge, probably it's a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1356698). On Launchpad, there are some ways to get around it.

Comment: @PNG Yes, apparently the bug was triggered and I solved it with [Comment 8](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1356698/comments/8)'s fix, except that I chose `"en_MX.UTF-8"` instead of the suggested `en_US` value. The clock shows as 12-hour format now, except that it doesn't display AM or PM, even though I made sure `%l:%M %p` is set for custom-time-format. I wonder what else is broken...

Comment: this answer does not work with elementary OS 0.4.1

Answer (score 1):

If you go to System Settings > Date & Time, at the bottom there is "Time Format:" just change that to AM/PM.

[image]

Comment: I'm using elementary Freya and i don't have this option, are you sure about this?

Comment: This option is present in Luna, but not in Freya.

Comment: It is present on Freya also, it is what I am currently using.

Comment: @JasonLysinger did you add the daily PPA to your sources?

Comment: @Rafael, I did not add the daily PPA. This option has always been available to me straight from first install.

Comment: @JasonLysinger The option was not originally available to me (the Settings panel was the first thing I tried). However after trying the `gsettings set` from another answer, the option suddenly appeared, but the clock was gone. After fixing the clock, the option is gone again. I guess it's something related to locales.